# Add fractional number of years to date in pandas Python

Tags: pandas, date

I have a pandas df that includes two columns: `time_in_years` (float64) and `date` (datetime64).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2009-12-25','2005-01-09','2010-10-31'],
    'time_in_years': ['10.3434','5.0977','3.3426']
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df["time_in_years"] = df.time_in_years.astype(float)
```

I need to create `date2` as a datetime64 column by adding the number of years to the date.

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
df['date_2'] = df['date'] + datetime.timedelta(years=df['time_in_years'])
```

I know that with fractions I will not be able to get the exact date, but I want to get the closest new date as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try package `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

First convert fractional years to number of days, then use lambda function and apply it to dataframe:

```
df['date_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] + relativedelta(days = int(x['time_in_years']*365)), axis = 1)
```

Result:

```
        date  time_in_years     date_2
0 2009-12-25        10.3434 2020-04-26
1 2005-01-09         5.0977 2010-02-12
2 2010-10-31         3.3426 2014-03-04
```

`datetime.timedelta` also works fine:

```
df['date_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'] + datetime.timedelta(days = int(x['time_in_years']*365)), axis = 1)
```

Please note conversion to `int` is necessary, because `relativedelta` and `timedelta` do not accept fractional values.

Comment: I was curious whether a faster solution is available. Given the size of data I have, this solution takes quite some time to complete. Thanks!